# RPC__E_DISCONNECTED error(0x80010108) while calling a callback aftre 6 mins

Tags: c++, com, rpc

I have an issue with my COM application.
The Call sequence is as follows.

COM client(STA) calls GetData() of a COM dll passing a callback pointer. GetData() has a while loop which takes a long time(more than 6 minutes)
COM dll Marshalls the interface and it  creates a thread. The thread enters an MTA and unmarshalles the call back pointer and calls OnGetData() of COM client.
But when calling the callback function(OnGetData() ) the call doesn't reach the Client, instead I get RPC__E_DISCONNECTED error(0x80010108).

How can I solve this error?
If its a normal scenario that it time outs in 6 minutes, is there any way to change the time out?

Comment: When you marshal an interface, you can pass a MSHLFLAGS_NOPING flag: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/171414/how-to-turn-off-the-com-garbage-collection-mechanism and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678428.aspx ,otherwise, please share some reproducing code.

Comment: CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream  is being used

Comment: Read the doc. This is just a wrapper on 1. create stream 2. call CoMarshalInterface 3. return stream to caller, so you can replace this call and use the MSHLFLAGS_NOPING flag